# Force user input via command line in python

Tags: python, parsing, input, command-line, args

Say I'm running a script from the command line;

```
$python hello.py
```

This hello.py script will print 'Hello, Welcome!' And the in next line it prompts you to enter the name. Example.

```
$python hello.py

"Hello, welcome!"

What is you name?:<here you enter the name and press enter for the program to continue>
```

Instead I want to parse my name while calling the script.

```
$python hello.py <do something to parse the name>
```

I know we can import sys and the name can be called via args[1]

I was wondering if there is a way without modifying the code and changing the way we run the script via command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the answer to the script:

```
echo "John Smith" | python hello.py
```

or use a here-string:

```
python hello.py <<<"John Smith"
```

If you want to feed more than just one line of input, a here-doc is easier:

```
python hello.py <<EOF
Answer to first question
Answer to second question
and so on
EOF
```

Comment: If I want a bash script to call hello.py and do the same thing, how can I do it?

Comment: There's no difference, you just put what I wrote in the script.

Comment: I do not understand. Say My bash script is cmd = "python hello.py"; res=${cmd};, How do I change res here to include echo "John Smith |"?

Comment: `res=$($cmd <<<"John Smith")`